# Checking a value falls between three ranges in Python

Tags: python

I am currently learning Python and want to ensure I am using good python practices and need some help in finding the best way of checking whether a value falls between different ranges.

Basically I am trying to find whether a cpu utilization is between 0-33 (green), 34-66 (amber) or 67-100 (red).  Here's my current code;

```
green = 33
amber = 66
red   = 100  # Probably not needed, but there for completeness

if cpu <= green:
   print "green"
elif cpu > amber:
   print "red"
else:
   print "amber"
```

Is there a better way to achieve this in Python?

I've looked at "Interval Comparisons" and that doesn't seem to quite fit the bill - although it is entirely possible that I haven't understood them correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham why?

Comment: @wim, read it wrong, the ordering is confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a trivial piece of code, and is readable enough. But if you had more intervals, you would need a loop. Here is an example:

```
for level_max, level in [(33, 'green'), (66, 'amber'), (100, 'red')]:
    if cpu <= level_max:
        print level
        break
```

Comment: This seems like a more graceful way of doing things, many thanks for your help - much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's hardly any simpler in your case, but in general you can the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module for comparisons like this.

```
limits = [33, 66, 100]
names = ['green', 'amber', 'red']
interval = bisect.bisect_left(limits, cpu)
print names[interval]
```

Comment: Don't you think it's a bit overkill to use binary search for 3 values?

Answer (score 2):

That is fine.  This might be more readable, because the order of logic in the code is matching the escalation of levels:

```
if cpu <= green:
   print "green"
elif cpu <= amber:
   print "amber"
else:
   print "red"
```